# Different output in Eclipse and WinSCP(Putty)

Tags: java, eclipse

my program works and i get the desired output in eclipse, however on putty it fails.

The desired output is:
[Eclipse Output]

[image]

However on putty i get this:

[image]

So after every "Command....." text there shoukld be some output and then "----------".However it only prints command text and "--------". Does anybody knows why? I mean why it is different from the output that is in Eclipse?

Here is my Main class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
/**
 * @author Habil Ganbarli
 * Date:   17.04.2017
 * Project: Mini-Facebook Application
 *
 */
public class Main {

    public static void app_Start(String file) throws ParseException{
        try {
            // Reading text file line by line 
             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(file));
             while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
             String line = scanner.nextLine();
             line = line.trim();
             // check if line is not empty
             if(!line.isEmpty()){
                 // Split lines for arguments and execute needed funtions
                 String[] array_as_line = line.split("  ");
                 if(array_as_line[0].equals("ADDUSER")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     UserCollection.addNewUser(array_as_line[1], array_as_line[2], array_as_line[3], array_as_line[4], array_as_line[5]);
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("REMOVEUSER")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     UserCollection.removeUser(Integer.parseInt(array_as_line[1]));
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("LISTUSERS")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).isSignIn()==true){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).listUsers();
                         }
                     }
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("SHOWPOSTS")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     UserCollection.showPosts(array_as_line[1]);
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("SIGNIN")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     UserCollection.UserSignIn(array_as_line[1], array_as_line[2]);
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("SIGNOUT")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).isSignIn()==true){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).SignOut();
                         }
                     }

                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("UPDATEPROFILE")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).getName().equals(array_as_line[1])){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).UpdateProfileInfo(array_as_line[1], array_as_line[2], array_as_line[3]);
                         }
                     }
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("CHPASS")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).isSignIn()==true){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).ChangePassword(array_as_line[1], array_as_line[2]);
                         }
                     }

                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("ADDFRIEND")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).isSignIn()==true){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).addFriend(array_as_line[1]);
                         }
                     }
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("REMOVEFRIEND")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).isSignIn()==true){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).removeFriend(array_as_line[1]);
                         }
                     }
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("ADDPOST-TEXT")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).isSignIn()==true){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).addTextPost(array_as_line[1],Double.parseDouble( array_as_line[2]), Double.parseDouble(array_as_line[3]), array_as_line[4]);
                         }
                     }
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("ADDPOST-IMAGE")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).isSignIn()==true){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).addImagePost(array_as_line[1],Double.parseDouble( array_as_line[2]), Double.parseDouble(array_as_line[3]), array_as_line[4],array_as_line[5],array_as_line[6]);
                         }
                     }
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("ADDPOST-VIDEO")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).isSignIn()==true){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).addVideoPost(array_as_line[1],Double.parseDouble( array_as_line[2]), Double.parseDouble(array_as_line[3]), array_as_line[4],array_as_line[5],Integer.parseInt(array_as_line[6]));
                         }
                     }
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("REMOVELASTPOST")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).isSignIn()==true){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).removeLastPost();
                         }
                     }
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("BLOCK")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).isSignIn()==true){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).blockUser(array_as_line[1]);
                         }
                     }
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("UNBLOCK")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).isSignIn()==true){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).unblockUser(array_as_line[1]);
                         }
                     }
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("LISTFRIENDS")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).isSignIn()==true){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).listFriends();
                         }
                     }
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("SHOWBLOCKEDFRIENDS")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).isSignIn()==true){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).showBlockedFriends();
                         }
                     }
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }else if(array_as_line[0].equals("SHOWBLOCKEDUSERS")){
                     System.out.println("Command: " + line);
                     for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.getUser_objects().size();i++){
                         if(UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).isSignIn()==true){
                             UserCollection.getUser_objects().get(i).showBlockedUsers();
                         }
                     }
                     System.out.println("-----------------------");
                 }
             }
             }
             scanner.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
             System.out.println("No File Found!");
             return;
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {
        UserCollection.fill_user_arraylist(args);
        UserCollection.addUserfromTxtFile();
        app_Start(args[1]);
    }

}
```

And here is my UserCollection class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserCollection {

    public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
        LineNumberReader reader  = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(filename));
        int cnt = 0;
        String lineRead = "";
        while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {}
        cnt = reader.getLineNumber(); 
        reader.close();
        return cnt;
    }

    public static  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> to2DList(String filePath,int rownum) throws FileNotFoundException{
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> final_arraylist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();  
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
             String line = scanner.nextLine();
             String[] line_array = line.trim().split("\t");
             final_arraylist.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line_array)));

        }
        scanner.close();
        return final_arraylist;
    }

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> user_arraylist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    private static ArrayList<User> user_objects = new ArrayList<User>();

    public static void fill_user_arraylist(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        user_arraylist = to2DList(args[0], countLines(args[0]));
    }

    public static void addUserfromTxtFile() throws ParseException{
        for(int i=0;i<user_arraylist.size();i++){
            String obj_name = UserCollection.user_arraylist.get(i).get(0);
            User user = new User(UserCollection.user_arraylist.get(i).get(0), UserCollection.user_arraylist.get(i).get(1), UserCollection.user_arraylist.get(i).get(2), UserCollection.user_arraylist.get(i).get(3), UserCollection.user_arraylist.get(i).get(4));
            user_objects.add(user); 
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<User> getUser_objects() {
        return user_objects;
    }

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getUser_arraylist() {
        return user_arraylist;
    }

    public UserCollection(){

    }

    public static void addNewUser(String name,String username,String password,String DateOfbirth,String graduatedSchool) throws ParseException{
        User user = new User(name,username,password,DateOfbirth,graduatedSchool);
        UserCollection.getUser_objects().add(user);
        System.out.println(name + " has been successfully added.");
    }

    public static void removeUser(int userID){
        int check = 0;
        int index = 0;
        for(int u = 0;u<UserCollection.user_objects.size();u++){
            if(UserCollection.user_objects.get(u).getUserId()==userID){
                index = u;
                check++;
            }
        }
        if(check !=0){
            UserCollection.getUser_objects().remove(index);
            System.out.println("User has been succesfully removed.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("No such user!");
        }

        //System.out.println("User has been succesfully removed");
    }

    public static void UserSignIn(String username,String password){
        int checkUser = 0;
        int checkUserPassMatch = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.user_objects.size();i++){
            if(UserCollection.user_objects.get(i).getUserName().equals(username)){
                checkUser++;
            }
            if(UserCollection.user_objects.get(i).getUserName().equals(username) && UserCollection.user_objects.get(i).getPassword().equals(password)){
                checkUserPassMatch++;
            }
        }
        if(checkUser != 0){
            if(checkUserPassMatch !=0){
                for(int i=0;i<UserCollection.user_objects.size();i++){
                    if(UserCollection.user_objects.get(i).getUserName().equals(username) && UserCollection.user_objects.get(i).getPassword().equals(password)){
                        UserCollection.user_objects.get(i).setSignInTrue();
                        System.out.println("You have successfully signed in.");
                    }
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Invalid username or password! Please try again.");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("No such user!");
        }
    }

    public static void showPosts(String username){
        int checkIfUserExists = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<user_objects.size();i++){
            if(user_objects.get(i).getUserName().equals(username)){
                checkIfUserExists++;
            }
        }
        if(checkIfUserExists != 0){
            for(int i=0;i<user_objects.size();i++){
                if(user_objects.get(i).getUserName().equals(username)){
                    if(user_objects.get(i).getCollection_post().size() != 0){
                        System.out.println("**************\n" + username + "'s Posts\n**************");
                        for(int p=0;p<user_objects.get(i).getCollection_post().size();p++){
                            System.out.println(user_objects.get(i).getCollection_post().get(p).toString());
                            System.out.println("----------------------");
                        }
                    }else{
                        System.out.println(username + " does not have any posts yet.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("No such user!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your codes that we can investigate the issue.

Comment: I have added 2 main classes of the program, Could you please help me?Could it be because of some argument passing?

Comment: Thank you very much.So basically it is my assignment and it consists of 8 classes and one interface. I transferred al my .java files and 2 text files(users.txt and commands.txt) to winscp server. then i ran it on putty by these commands: "javac Main.java" then "java Main users.txt commands.txt". the thing is that, i am just curious what is the reason for different results?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142867/discussion-between-gurtug-gungor-and-habil-ganbarli).

Answer (score 1):

Its all about way that `javac` works on putty when it compiles class files. Its full name is `Java Programming Language Compiler` and it has this arguments with types as command:

```
javac [ options ] [ sourcefiles ] [ classes] [ @argfiles ]
```

When you upload your files to putty server and try to compile more than one without any certain relationship(inheritance, implementation, package-class dependency etc.) with `javac`, it takes the file name that you wrote(assume that you used `javac fileName.java`) and starts to work on it. If it founds a bound with another file while compiling, it compiles it too. However in this specific situation ([as we discussed on chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142867/discussion-between-gurtug-gungor-and-habil-ganbarli)) this program' some class files don't have certain relationships with others so compiler *ignores* their bounds.

So you should write your file names, paths and etc. like it shown above. Also you can find more and detailed information on [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html). Don't mind about correcting me or adding something to it, Have a good day!